# mongodb get distinct values with category

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Suppose there is the following collection

People:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    name: 'john',
    last_name: 'blah1',
    job: 'lifeguard'
}
{
    _id: 2,
    name: 'john',
    last_name: 'blah2',
    job: 'lifeguard'
}
{
    _id: 3,
    name: 'alex',
    last_name: 'blah3',
    job: 'lifeguard'
}
{
    _id: 4,
    name: 'alex',
    last_name: 'blah4',
    job: 'lifeguard'
}
{
    _id: 5,
    name: 'alex',
    last_name: 'blah5',
    job: 'gardener'
}
```

I need to get the distict jobs with an array of distict names:

Trying to get the following result:

```
[
    {
        value: 'lifeguard',
        names: [
            'john',
            'alex'
        ],
    },
    {
        value: 'gardener',
        names: [
            'alex'
        ],
    },
]
```

I understand how to get the unique jobs

```
db.people.find().distinct('jobs')
```

However i did not figure out how to do a distinct query with multiple properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better to use the aggregation framework where you have a pipeline that has a **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** stage to group the documents by the job key and then construct the names distinct array within the group by the accumulator **[`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/#grp._S_addToSet)**.

Consider the following aggregate operation:

```
db.people.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$job",
            "names": { "$addToSet": "$name" }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: thanks, you helped e finally understand how the aggregate function works.

Comment: Hello, would you know the answer to this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44041506/how-to-check-that-a-user-has-already-voted-on-a-post

Answer (score 0):

@chridam did help me find the right answer, in the real world my object was more like

```
{
    _id: 1,
    name: ['john', 'bah1', 'blah2', 'blah3'],
    last_name: 'blah1',
    job: 'lifeguard'
}
```

so i had to [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the names and aggregate $group just like in @chridam's answer.

```
model.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$name"},
    {
        $group: {
            _id:"$name",
            jobs: {
                $addToSet: "$job"
            }
        }
    }
]
```